# Why Type Casting of larger variable to smaller variable results in modulo of larger variable by the range of smaller variable

Tags: java, typecasting-operator

Recently,while I was going through typecasting concept in java, I have seen that type casting of larger variable to smaller variable results in the modulo of larger variable by the range of smaller variable.Can anyone please explain this in detail why this is the case and is it true for any explicit type conversion?.

```
     class conversion {
    public static void main(String args[]) 
    {
        double a = 295.04;
        int  b = 300;
        byte c = (byte) a;
        byte d = (byte) b;
        System.out.println(c + " "  + d);
    } 
}
```

The above code gives the answer of d as 44 since 300 modulo 256 is 44.Please explain why this is the case and also what happens to the value of c?

Comment: have you ever given a thought if b =128, then modulo works but why negative??? check that

Comment: comment 2: and also, if b=255, then modulo doesn't work, check that too.

Comment: yeah i think I know answer for that.Since Byte data type range is 0 to 127,overflow occurs if we cross 127,so it counts back from -128 to -1.this is why we wont get the correct answer for b=255.Correct me if I am wrong?

Comment: *"Since Byte data type range is 0 to 127"* - Incorrect.  -128 to +127

Comment: yeah right thanks for the correction

Comment: better is to understand how bits are chopped off in case of explicit casting. that will give you better understanding. @SaiSankalp

Comment: Yeah thanks @TahirHussainMir

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a design decision that goes all the way back the the C programming language and possibly to C's antecedents too.

What happens when you convert from a larger integer type to a smaller integer type is that the top bits are lopped off.

Why?  Originally (and currently) because that is what hardware integer instructions support.

The "other" logical way to do this (i.e. NOT the way that Java defines integer narrowing) would be to convert to that largest (or smallest) value representable in the smaller type; e.g.

```
    // equivalent to real thin in real java
    // b = (byte) (Math.max(Math.min(i, 127), -128))
```

would give +127 as the value of `b`.  Incidentally, this is what happens when you convert a floating-point value to an integer value, and the value is too large.  That is what is happening in your `c` example.

---

You also said:

> The above code gives the answer of d as 44 since 300 modulo 256 is 44.

In fact, the correct calculation would be:

```
int d = ((b + 128) % 256) - 128;
```

That is because the range of the Java `byte` type is -128 to +127.

---

For completeness, the above behavior only happens in Java when the larger type is an integer type.  If the larger type is a floating point type and the smaller one is an integer type, then a source value that is too large or too small (or an infinity) gets converted to the largest or smallest possible integer value for the target type; e.g.

```
double x = 1.0e200;
int i = (int) x;   // assigns 'Integer.MAX_VALUE' to 'i'
```

And a NaN is converted to zero.

Reference:

- [Java 17 Language Specification: §5.1.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.3)

Comment: But the value of b in your example should be 44 right?

Comment: the "other way" explanation is good , but the output here indicates `c` is `39` (which is `295 mod 256 `), I think that the `double` is converted into an `int` first then to a `byte`. At least this is how it is done in C++.

Comment: can you explain why we need to do modulo division to get the result?

Comment: @SaiSankalp 1) No.  I am describing the "other way" ... which Java does NOT implement.  2) Because modulo 256 and "chopping off the top bits" do exactly the same thing.

Comment: It goes back at least as far as Algol-60 and COBOL-60, if not the original Fortran '57.

Comment: It gets a bit borderline.  IIRC, Algol-60 and classical FORTRAN only had one integer type ... so large int -> small int casting was not an issue.  As for COBOL ... well the data model was plain "weird" by today's standards.  C's primary antecedent was reputed to be BCPL ... the language with only one data type according to its author :-)

Comment: The min/max clamping on overflow is called "saturation".  Fun fact: some SIMD instruction sets provide narrowing with signed or unsigned saturation instead of truncation, e.g. x86 SSE2 [`packssdw`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/packsswb:packssdw) packs 32 -> 16-bit integers with signed saturation.  (Also add/sub with saturation instead of wrapping is available; useful for audio/image processing.)